# Limit resize in Fabric.js

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to limit max object resize in Fabric.js. I'm using `observe("object:scaling")` with this code:

```
canvasLI.observe("object:scaling", function(e) {
var shape = e.target;
var scaleX = shape.scaleX;
var scaleY = shape.scaleY;
var posX = shape.left;
var posY = shape.top;

if(!isNaN(scaleX) && scaleX > 2)
    {
    shape.set({
        scaleX: 2,          
        });
    }
if(!isNaN(scaleY) && scaleY > 2)
    {
    shape.set({
        scaleY: 2,
        });
    }
shape.set({
    left: posX,
    top: posY,
    });
console.log("X:" + ( shape.scaleX) + " Y:" + (shape.scaleY));
});
```

It works fine, and limit max size in scale, **but when one object has scale limit** and try to resize again, **it moves following the mouse cursor** on top and bottom-left controls (not in bottom-right control).

Also, I tried to capture `left` and `top` values in the object to move it to these values, but doesn't work.

Thanks.

PS: Also tried to change `shape.width` and `shape.height` instead of scaleX and scaleY and the problem is the same.

EDIT:

I have been could stop the movement of the object on scaling adding `lockScalingX:true and lockScalingY:true` to the code on max-scale, but now I have another problem. How I can disable this lockScaling putting this value to false when I scale DOWN? How I can get the event of scale DOWN?

Comment: I have been could stop the movement of the object on scaling adding `lockScalingX:true and lockScalingY:true` to the code on max-scale, but now I have another problem. How I can disable this lockScaling putting this value to false when I scale DOWN? How I can get the event of scale DOWN?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback onBeforeScaleRotate

```
canvas.onBeforeScaleRotate = function lock(object) { 
    object.set({ lockScalingX:false, lockScalingY: false  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will stop the object to resize over the canvas size and resize in the reverse side.

```
 canvas.on('object:scaling', function(event){ 
        var el = event.target;
          if (el && (el.height*el.scaleX) > 10 && (el.left + (el.width*el.scaleX)) < canvas.width && (el.top + (el.height*el.scaleY)) < canvas.height){
            previous_scaleY=el.scaleY;           
            previous_scaleX=el.scaleX;
            previous_left=el.left;
            previous_top=el.top;
         }
        if(el && (el.height*el.scaleX) <10) {
             el.left=previous_left;
             el.top=previous_top;
             el.scaleX=previous_scaleX;
             el.scaleY=previous_scaleY;
             el.lockScalingX=true;
             el.lockScalingY= true;
             canvas.renderAll();
        }
       if (el && (el.left + (el.width*el.scaleX)) > canvas.width || (el.top + (el.height*el.scaleY)) > canvas.height){
            console.log('mOVINGGGGGGGGGGGGG');
            el.left=previous_left;
            el.top=previous_top;
            console.log('Scale X:'+el.scaleX);
            console.log('Scale Y:'+el.scaleY);
            console.log('width:'+el.width);
            console.log('Height:'+el.height);

            console.log('Previous Y: '+previous_scaleY);  // PREVIOUS SCALE X & Y WILL COME FROM MOUSE DOWN EVENT
            el.scaleX=previous_scaleX;
            el.scaleY=previous_scaleY;
            canvas.renderAll();

            }

      });

 canvas.observe('mouse:up', function (e) {
          var activeObject = e.target;
          activeObject.lockScalingX=false;  // this will connect with object scalling event
           activeObject.lockScalingY= false;
});
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: Any idea how to stop resizing entirely? Cause when you hit the other side of the canvas it still doesn't stop there. I described a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54826801/limit-object-resizing just the other way around but no one seems to have an answer.